# Bootstrap modal confirmation delete

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys I'm trying to delete a record/row from my table using a modal delete confirmation. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
});

$("#btn-delete").click(function(e) {
  $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
});

});
</script>

         <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <?php
                    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT project_code, description
                          FROM tblprojects" );
                    $stmt2->execute();

                    for($i=0; $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(); $i++){
                       $project = $row2['project_code'];
                       $desc = $row2['description'];
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="project-detail.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>">
                        <?php echo $project; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $desc; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="update-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" title="Update record">
                        <i class="icon-edit icon-white">
                        </i>
                    </a></td>
                    <td><a href="#<?php echo $project; ?>"
                  id="<?php echo $project; ?>"
                  data-id="<?php echo $project; ?>"
                  class="btn-show-modal" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete record">
                  <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></a></td>

                  <div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5>Confirm Delete</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="modaltext">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
                      </div>    

                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">No<a>
                        <a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" 
                          class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-delete">Yes<a>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </tr>
                    <?php 
                    } 
                    ?>
            </table>
```

But the problem is, when I am about to delete the last row the one that gets deleted is the first row. Why is it like that? Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the link that's generated in `<a href="">` is wrong, or your delete-project.php does not work correctly..

Comment: the problem lies within `delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>` I think, make sure `$project` point to the code of last row id

Comment: @zeroriku yes that's the problem I don't know how to point the correct row id, but when I hover over other row on the table I can see the id correct, but when I'm inside the bootstrap modal, I hovered and only saw the first row id

Comment: answered your question in the case you want to have multiple modal, though I personally suggest AngularJS to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the modal generation and passing the $project value.

You are using a loop as

```
for($i=0; $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(); $i++){
                       $project = $row2['project_code'];
                       $desc = $row2['description'];
                    ?>
```

And inside the above loop you are generating the modals so basically you will have many modals which are equal to the num of rows in the query.

Now all of them are having the same "id" i.e. "dialog-example" and once you click on the delete it pop ups the first modal from the DOM and is deleting wrong data.

**Solution** 
For each modal you give the id as

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example_<?php echo $project; ?>">
```

Then in the blow code

```
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
});
```

Get the id of the element using attr("id") and append this at the end of

```
"dialog-example_"+{id you received}
```

The same thing you need to do for the hide modal as well.

```
UPDATE ON HOW TO DO IT
```

Give the modal div id as

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example_<?php echo $project; ?>">
```

Then in the click function to as

$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var modal_id = "dialog-example_"+id;
  $("#"+modal_id).modal('show');
});

Change

```
<a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" 
                          class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-delete">Yes<a>
```

to

```
<a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" 
                          class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo $project ;?>">Yes<a>
```

AND finally

```
    $("#btn-delete").click(function(e) {
  $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
});
```

to

```
$(".btn btn-danger").click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var modal_id = "dialog-example_"+id;
  $("#"+modal_id).modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! finally I got it to work. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

**On topic**

Problem is you have multiple modals. But select it on 1 id. So jQuery will select the first value.

A solution would be to put the delete url in an hidden input field. Then when the user clicks the open delete modal you select the url and put it in the a tag.

*Example time*

**JavaScript Part**

```
$(function(){
  $(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
    // put the right url in the delete
    $("#dialog-example .delete-url").attr('href', $(this).attr('data-delete-url');
    $("#dialog-example").modal('show');

    return e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btn-delete").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
  });
});
```

**PHP part**

*I assume $stmt is prepared etc*

```
<ul>
  <? foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $record) : ?>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="delete" data-delete-url="?id=<?= $record['project_code']; ?>">delete</a>
    </li>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5>Confirm Delete</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p class="modaltext">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">No<a>
    <a class="delete-url btn btn-danger">Yes<a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code explaind**
It is not handy to put an bootstrap modal in an `foreach`/`for`/`while` unless you change the id. But then again lot of duplicate code.

What the code does it changes the delete-url on the fly depending on which `a` the user clicked

**Off topic**

I highly recommend using the `foreach` for your iteration of the data records instead of a for loop.

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT project_code, description
    FROM tblprojects" );
$stmt2->execute();

for($i=0; $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(); $i++){ /** code **/}
```

would be

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT project_code, description
    FROM tblprojects" );
$stmt2->execute();

foreach($stmt2->fetchAll() as $record){}
```

Comment: So how can I get each field?

Comment: How do you mean? If you mean the off topic, then `$record` == `$row2`. So you can access it like `$record['project_id']`

Comment: Okay I got, but the topic I posted still I'm not getting the correct row.

Comment: Updated the answer with a example of how I would do it, with only the delete link, not tested the code but should work

Answer (score 0):

Because when you open the modal, it open the first `#dialog-example` div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find("#dialog-example").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Can you post some sample of that:?

Comment: added an example for you

Comment: what is the id^= for?

Comment: sorry just now code does not solve the problem, try something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

because you generate modal for every row this is wrong !
and show modal(first modal show) this is wrong!(this delete first row)
create one modal and set parameter with jquery e.g

```
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
  $("#dialog-example #btn-delete").attr('href','delete-project.php?code='+$(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

good luck

Comment: So is it correct to put inside the for loop my modal code?

Comment: Okay. So I placed it outside the loop, how can I capture the row id?

Comment: it's in post code last line `$(this).attr('data-id')` when click trash icon

Comment: I put the data-id and then tried to delete, it's not getting the row id.

Comment: I'm getting undefined.

Comment: set class for trash button like `delbutton` and replace `$(".btn-show-modal").click` with `$(".delbutton").click` and replace `data-id` with `id`

Comment: if you get undefined again check you element `id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49387/discussion-between-neknek-mouh-and-saman-khademi)