# How do I fix the deletion of current row when an img is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I've been cracking my head at trying to use a modal as a confirmation to delete a specific row from my database. The SQL works, but only without the modal. (the modal is required)

From earlier searches I have tried and failed to implement the tips from [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296054/bootstrap-modal-confirmation-delete).

```
    while ($row = $statement ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    Here I create a variable to use later
    <?php $username = $row['username']; ?>   

        <td>
            <div class="adjust-buttons">

                <input 
                type="image" 
                id="delete" 
                alt="delete" 
                src="../img/delete.png" 
                onclick="showModal();" 
                onmouseover="this.src='../img/delete-hover.png';" 
                onmouseout="this.src='../img/delete.png';">


                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <h3>Delete user</h3>

                        <?php
                    echo 'are you sure you want ' .$username. '     removed?';
                        ?>

                        <input 
                            class="modal-button" 
                            type="button" 
                            value="Cancel" 
                            onclick="hideModal();">

                        <input 
                            class="modal-button" 
                            type="button" 
                            value="I'm sure" 
                            id="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" 
                            onclick="document.location.href='../delete-user/delete-user.php?username=<?php echo $row['username']?>'" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I expected the row deleted to be the one which is selected from the loop. This is not the case, only the first created row is selected no matter which delete button I press.

Comment: try to post your complete code.The above code hardly explains

Answer (score 0):

Just create a link on that input and it would work fine.

```
<a href='delete-user/delete-user.php?username=<?=$row['username']?>'>
<input class="modal-button" type="button" value="I'm sure" />
</a>
```

or, you can do it like this

```
onclick="deleteUser('<?=$row['username']?>')"

function deleteUser(username){
    window.location.href = "project_url_delete"+username;
}
```

Comment: Or keep the HTML valid by making it a form with a submit button?

Answer (score 0):

```
    while ($row = $statement ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

Here I create a variable to use later
<?php $username = $row['username']; ?>   

    <td>
        <div class="adjust-buttons">

            <input 
            type="image" 
            id="delete" 
            alt="delete" 
            src="../img/delete.png" 
            onclick="showModal('<?php echo $row['username']; ?>');" 
            onmouseover="this.src='../img/delete-hover.png';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='../img/delete.png';">


            <div id="myModal<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <h3>Delete user</h3>

                    <?php
                echo 'are you sure you want ' .$username. '     removed?';
                    ?>

                    <input 
                        class="modal-button" 
                        type="button" 
                        value="Cancel" 
                        onclick="hideModal();">

                    <input 
                        class="modal-button" 
                        type="button" 
                        value="I'm sure" 
                        id="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" 
                        onclick="document.location.href='../delete-user/delete-user.php?username=<?php echo $row['username']?>'" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

and onclick method

```
function showModal(modal_id)
{
  $('#myModal'+modal_id).show('modal');
 }
```

try this...